# Using JQuery .slide and .show together

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a drop down menu plugin and was studying code for reference and I came across a line of code that displays the drop down.

I was curious to know why .slide().show() are chained together like this when both will display the menu. Is this for degradation purposes or what?

---

Here's the context I see it in:

```
$('.selector').find('ul').slideDown().show();
```

Just an example I've seen around, but never understood why use both.

Comment: Could you show us the code?  Some context would certainly be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In that context it's definitely a fallback .show() without any easing will instantly make an item visible, and provided that it's got no amended styles to it return it to it's visible state. By fallback I mean that if any problems with .slideDown happen it will return to it's "default" state or what it would have looked like before anything had been done to it.

While 99.5% of the time it will never be needed, if you have any errors in the setTimout animation loop in slideDown (client lag, bad ram etc) it will be out of position and probably semi transparent. Netbooks and ipads boat are slim on gpu & some times ram, and this is a safe guard against a badly rendered final state.

see: http://api.jquery.com/show/

> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except
>   that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If
>   an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it
>   will once again be displayed inline.